# Error al recibir variable por metodo POST

Tags: php, post

hola estoy intentando recibir una variable en php, desde el metodo POST e mirado cual sera el error y no lo encuentro, se que es algo muy sencillo pero no me funciona esta vez,si alguien me puede instruir seria de gran ayuda muchas gracias

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilos/menu.css">
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">

<body>

    <form name="formulario1" method="post" action="controllers/controller_menu.php">
        <div class="superior">
        <label for="seleccione">Falta Cometida</label>

        <select class="seleccion" name="cosa" onchange="cambia()">
            <option value="0">Seleccione
            <option value="1">Academica
            <option value="2">Aptitudinal

        </select>

        <select class="seleccion" id="opt" name="opt">
            <option value="-">-
        </select>
    <input id="salir" type="submit" value="Salir">
            <input type="button" value="Registrar"  OnClick="location.href='controllers/controller_menu.php'">

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //1) Definir Las Variables Correspondintes
        var opt_1 = new Array ("Seleccione una opcion", "Plagiar materiales, trabajos...", "Forza", "DOTA2", "...");
        var opt_2 = new Array ("Seleccione una opcion", "Disco Duro", "SSD", "CPU", "...");
        // 2) crear una funcion que permita ejecutar el cambio dinamico

        function cambia(){
            var cosa;
            //Se toma el vamor de la "cosa seleccionada"
            cosa = document.formulario1.cosa[document.formulario1.cosa.selectedIndex].value;
            //se chequea si la "cosa" esta definida
            if(cosa!=0){
                //selecionamos las cosas Correctas
                mis_opts=eval("opt_" + cosa);
                //se calcula el numero de cosas
                num_opts=mis_opts.length;
                //marco el numero de opt en el select
                document.formulario1.opt.length = num_opts;
                //para cada opt del array, la pongo en el select
                for(i=0; i<num_opts; i++){
                    document.formulario1.opt.options[i].value=mis_opts[i];
                    document.formulario1.opt.options[i].text=mis_opts[i];
                }
                }else{
                    //si no habia ninguna opt seleccionada, elimino las cosas del select
                    document.formulario1.opt.length = 1;
                    //ponemos un guion en la unica opt que he dejado
                    document.formulario1.opt.options[0].value="-";
                    document.formulario1.opt.options[0].text="-";
                }
                //hacer un reset de las opts
                document.formulario1.opt.options[0].selected = true;

            }



    </script>
</body>
```

aqui esta mi codigo php donde estoy llamando el dato que no funciona 
Undefined index: opt in

```
 <?php
    $variable=$_POST['opt'];
    echo $variable;
 ?>
```

ya revise bien la ruta y no creo que sea eso, de igual manera, tengo una carpeta llamada controllers y el archivo se llama controller_menu.php 
Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que tu boton tiene una redirección:

```
OnClick="location.href='controllers/controller_menu.php'
```

Ese onclick se ejecuta primero que el submit del form por lo que te lleva a ella sin los elementos del formulario en el post, quitando eso queda solucionado.

Saludos.

Comment: Por si acaso, el option del select que va a usar también está mal formado y no cerró la etiqueta

Answer (score 2):

Cambia:

```
<input type="button" value="Registrar"  OnClick="location.href='controllers/controller_menu.php'">
```

por esto:

```
<input type="submit" value="Registrar">
```

Comment: Serias tan amable de mirar [answer]. Tambien de paso hace el [tour].. Tene en cuenta que las preguntas que son solo codigo sin ninguna explicacion se consideran de baja calidad.